# Removing duplicate objects within a Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, duplicates, django-queryset

This is a question that I've seen asked a few times but I could not really find a solution that made much sense for my problem.

```
>>> query = ['software', 'engineer']
>>> hits = []
>>> for q in query:
...    x = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=q))
...    hits.append(x)
...
>>> hits
[<QuerySet [<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]>, <QuerySet [<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]>]
```

How can I clean up the hits QuerySet so it doesn't have any duplicates?

I tried the below but that was unsuccessful:

```
>>> hits = list(dict.fromkeys(hits))
>>> hits
[<QuerySet [<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]>, <QuerySet [<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]>]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rather chain Q objects in your filter and rather produce single query to database

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

words = ['software', 'engineer']
or_filter = reduce(or_, (Q(job_title__icontains=word) for word in words))


Vacancy.objects.filter(or_filter)
```

---

Or you could check if you already have that object in list prior to appending it in for instance by keeping set of object id's

Comment: I imported reduce because it through a Name error but now I am getting another Name error: `NameError: name 'or_' is not defined`

Comment: or_ is from operators module https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html. I have added import statements

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!!
Instead of **filter** it is better to use **get** that way instead of each item in the list being a QuerySet, each item is a Vacancy object and is easily accessible.

```
>>> for q in query:
...    x = Vacancy.objects.get(Q(job_title__icontains=q))
...    hits.append(x)
...
>>> hits
[<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>, <Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]
>>> hits = list(dict.fromkeys(hits))
>>> hits
[<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]
```

Comment: what happens if you have a lot of data in that model and the queryset with job_title =' software engineer returns let's say a billion rows You are going to store all this data in memory in the hits list?

Comment: Queryset manipulation as much as possible should be offloaded to the Database side either by using the inbuilt filters or writing custom SQL. The database is faster and built for this situations.

Comment: @SDRJ I edited my answer because I realised there is no need to specifically access the job_title.

Comment: @sarchi-xo- hits.append(x) . Think about this list if your application grows and you have a lot of data in the database and you are appending all this data in memory by storing it in a list. I don't know the exact use case you are working on but might be something to consider in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Covert to set and then again to list

```
hits=list(set(hits))
>>> hits
[<Vacancy: 6 Software Engineer>]
```

Answer (score -1):

@sarchi-xo - `Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=q)).distinct()`. Does this work ?

Just for more clarity. Here is a snapshot of the distinct() working perfectly fine on queryset. Not sure why you are receiving 'list object has no attribute distinct'

[image: distinct_demo]

Comment: He is not storing duplicates, he is doing query for each of words in his wordlist and appending results to hits list

Comment: Yes exactly what @iklinac said. Also I did try .distinct() and I got an Attribute error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'distinct'`.

Comment: @sarchi-xo- Try distinct on the queryset. It will not throw error.  x = Vacancy.objects.filter(Q(job_title__icontains=q)).distinct()

Comment: @SDRJ you have just repeated the same thing and I have already told you that I tried that and it did not work ?!

Comment: @sarchi-xo- I have even tested it myself. Added in a snapshot. Not sure why you are receiving the error.

Comment: @SDRJ I have solved it and posted my solution if you are interested.